# How a noun is considered to be specific?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

I learn to use "the" when I need to be specific.  But I am confused as I am not sure what is the meaning of being specific?  specific to the context I guess.
For example:-

***High income will not make one happy.***
I am talking generally about "high income"

***The high income did not make Costa happy.***
I am using "the" because the income is specific to Costa.

Did I get that right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the use of the definite article as being about something *specific* but you can also think of it as referring to something that's been *identified*.

For instance, although both of your examples sentences are correct (with no article or the definite article), so is the following:

> Having **a** high income did not make Costa happy.

Even though, as you say, it's specific to Costa, it's still being used in a general way. He may have had different incomes in different past years, and one of those happened to be high, as opposed to several others which were not.

---

In isolation, your single sentence with **the** sounds strange from a semantic perspective because it hasn't been put into context. If it were the *only* sentence, I would immediately ask, "*Which* high income?"

When you use **the**, you need to (at least figuratively) be able to point to something and say, "*that* one."

To provide context and make the use of the definite article natural, you can provide context in several different ways:

> ***In 2017,*** Costa made ***a lot of money***. But **the** high income did not make Costa happy.
>   **The** high income ***from his movie*** did not make Costa happy.
>   He had ***more money than he knew what to do with.*** **The** high income did not make Costa happy.
>   **The** high income he ***earned last year*** did not make Costa happy.

In all of the above sentences, we can answer the question, "*Which* high income?" It's been made clear in a previous sentence, or in the sentence that uses the definite article. For example: "*Which* high income?" "The one he earned last year."

---

With concrete nouns specifically (physical objects as opposed to concepts like high income), it's normally necessary to use **a** the first time we talk about something:

> ✔ She saw **a** dog. **The** dog looked hungry.

(*Which* dog? The one she saw.)

But unlike high income, it might still sound a bit strange if the two things were combined into a single sentence:

> ✘ One day, she was walking down **a** street. **The** dog she **saw on** ***the*** **street** looked hungry.

Although the second sentence sounds okay if read only it and not the first sentence, it's slightly jarring when put in context. You might think to yourself, "Did I miss something? I don't recall a dog being on the street." You might then read backwards to see if the dog had been mentioned before.

Even though the question about which *dog* is answered, it now becomes "Which *dog on the street*?" So, it's simply not idiomatic. In this sentence, even where the dog has been identified and specified, we would still normally use **a** the first time we mention it:

> ✔ One day, she was walking down **a** street. **A** dog she **saw on** ***the*** **street** looked hungry. **The** dog also had fleas.

---

So, not only do you need to keep in mind the answer to *Which?*, but you also need to remember the rule about **a** before **the** when using concrete nouns specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an example would help:

> Give me `a` book to put under the table leg.

There is no specific book I need, just one of the right thickness, so use the *indefinite* article.

> Give me `the` book in my bag.

I want one specific book, so use the *definite* article.

In your second example, no article is needed, but if one is used, as you state, it should be the *definite* article, referring to Costa's particular income.